# Printing out the list of nodes to the console

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

//Step 1: Get string from user
//Step 2: Find out how many times each character in the string repeats
//Step 3: find the two characters that repeat the least adding their frequency and add them together with the sum of their frequencies 
//step 4: Add this new sum back into the list, wherever it will now go, higher up
//step 5: repeat theses steps, until you have a huffman tree!


namespace HuffmanTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HuffmanTree.GetValue();
        }
    }

    class HuffmanTree
    {
        public static void GetValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a string to be encoded"); //Here we are asking the user to input a string
            string encodeme = Console.ReadLine(); // here the user inputs their string, which gets declared as the variable "encodeme"

            Dictionary<char, int> timesRepeated = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            List<Node> HuffmanNodes = new List<Node>();

            foreach (char ch in encodeme.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
            {
                if (timesRepeated.ContainsKey(ch))
                {
                    timesRepeated[ch] = timesRepeated[ch] + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    timesRepeated.Add(ch, 1);
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> item in timesRepeated.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value))
            {
                char key = item.Key;
                int count = item.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(key.ToString() + " : " + count.ToString());

               HuffmanNodes.Add(new Node());              
            }

            Console.WriteLine(HuffmanNodes(node));
        }

        public class Node //These are going to be the intialisation of our nodes
        {
            public char Symbol { get; set; }
            public int Frequency { get; set; }
            public Node Right { get; set; }
            public Node Left { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to `Console.Write` my Huffman tree node list so I can see what is going on. Printing `Console.WriteLine(HuffmanNodes(node));` doesn't seem to work. I have tried printing several different ways such as with `[i]` and it just does not seem to work. This is for debugging, so I can see whats going on with each individual step.

Comment: Add a print method to the Node class like this : public void Print(Node node){ Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}, Frequency : {1}", node.Symbol.ToString(), node.Frequency.ToString());}

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to invoke `HuffmanNodes` like a method when, because it is a `List<>`, you'll need to enumerate it...

```cs
foreach (Node node in HuffmanNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Symbol: {node.Symbol}, Frequency: {node.Frequency}");
}
```

...or iterate it...

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < HuffmanNodes.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Symbol: {HuffmanNodes[i].Symbol}, Frequency: {HuffmanNodes[i].Frequency}");
}
```

...to access each `Node` it contains.

You could also just incorporate the code to display the list in the preceding `foreach` loop, since that will give you access to the same `Node`s in the same order as they're added to the `List<>`...

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> item in timesRepeated.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value))
{
    // [snip]

    Node node = new Node();
    HuffmanNodes.Add(node);
    Console.WriteLine($"Symbol: {node.Symbol}, Frequency: {node.Frequency}");
}
```

Additional notes:

- You never set any of the properties of the `Node` you add to `HuffmanNodes`.
- If you `override` the [`ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) of the `Node` class you could build a diagnostic `string` much the same way as my `Console.WriteLine()` calls above.  This would allow you to print the properties of a `Node` with simply `Console.WriteLine(node);`.
- It's odd to have a method named `GetValue()` that doesn't return anything.